# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'topic' cannot be null

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to upload to my database a user entry under a subtopic. When I enter something into the `textarea` and click the add comment button, I get these two errors:

`Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'topic' cannot be null` &
`mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'topic' cannot be null`

I tried the other answers on here with the same question but unfortunately there weren't that many of them and they didn't help me.

I've used var dump to make sure it's not null and has a value (`var_dump($topic);`) and it does, this is what it outputted `E:\wamp64\www\theforum\subtopic.php:30:string 'Movies' (length=6)`. So I have no idea why is doesn't work. This is what my subtopic table looks like:

[Table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMlvB.png)

So can someone please help me find my bug ?

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(-1);

include 'includes/bootstrap.php';

$userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$sub_name = isset($_GET['sub_topic_name']) ? $_GET['sub_topic_name'] : $sub_name = 0;

$display_sub_topics = $con->prepare('SELECT topic, created_by FROM subtopic WHERE sub_topic = ?');
$display_sub_topics->bind_param("s", $sub_name);
$display_sub_topics->execute();
$display_sub_topics->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $display_sub_topics->num_rows;
$display_sub_topics->bind_result($topic, $created_by);
$display_sub_topics->fetch();

if (isset($_POST['add_button'])) {

    $topic = $topic ?? $topic;

    $comment_add = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic_replies (reply, added_by, subtopic, topic) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $comment_add->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['add_comment'], $userLoggedIn, $sub_name, $topic);
    $comment_add->execute();
}

var_dump($topic);
```

The form:

```
<form action="subtopic.php" method="POST">

        <textarea id="add_comment" rows="8" cols="70" name="add_comment" 
        placeholder="Add comment about topic"></textarea><br><br>

        <button id="add_button" name="add_button">Add Comment</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: what are the value of sub_topic in the database

Comment: @Basharmal nothing gets uploaded to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this work

```
include 'includes/bootstrap.php';

$userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['user_session'];


if (isset($_POST['add_button'])) {
  

$sub_name = (isset($_GET['sub_topic_name']) ? $_GET['sub_topic_name'] : '');


$display_sub_topics = $con->prepare('SELECT topic, created_by FROM subtopic WHERE sub_topic = ?');
$display_sub_topics->bind_param("s", $sub_name);
$display_sub_topics->execute();
$display_sub_topics->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $display_sub_topics->num_rows;
$display_sub_topics->bind_result($topic, $created_by);

 
while ($display_sub_topics->fetch()) {
        
      global $topic ;
   }
  if( !empty($_POST['add_comment']) ){
$comment_add = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic_replies (reply, 
  added_by, subtopic, topic) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $comment_add->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['add_comment'], $userLoggedIn, 
 $sub_name, $topic);
$comment_add->execute();
   }else{
 echo " textarea is empty";
   }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something a bit more direct

```
$sub_name = $_GET['sub_topic_name'] ?? '';

$display_sub_topics = $con->prepare('SELECT topic, created_by FROM subtopic WHERE sub_topic = ?');
$display_sub_topics->bind_param("s", $sub_name);
$display_sub_topics->execute();
$display_sub_topics->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $display_sub_topics->num_rows;
$display_sub_topics->bind_result($topic, $created_by);
$display_sub_topics->fetch();

if (isset($_POST['add_comment'])) {
    $topic = $topic ?? 'none';
    $comment_add = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic_replies (reply, added_by, subtopic, topic) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $comment_add->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['add_comment'], $_SESSION['user_session'], $sub_name, $topic);
    $comment_add->execute();
}
```

If this works, I simply added the variables directly to the bind AND made `$topic` always a string if it's not set.